# Flask-SocketIO app running on Gunicorn throws TypeError

Tags: python, gunicorn, flask-socketio, eventlet

I have a working Flask-SocketIO server but it is not working with Gunicorn. The relevant part of the server looks like this:

```
def main(env, resp):

    app = Flask(__name__,
                static_url_path='',
                static_folder='dist',
                template_folder='dist')

    socketio = SocketIO(app)

    @app.route('/')
    def home():
        return app.send_static_file('index.html')

    # socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000) I comment this out when using Gunicorn because otherwise it tries to run the process twice and throws an error.
```

I am using eventlet and running the following command as described in the Flask-SocketIO docs [here](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) :

`gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -b 0.0.0.0:8000 -w 1 index:main`

The gunicorn process starts fine, but when I navigate to the page I get the following server error:

```
Error handling request /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 55, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener_name, req, client, addr)
  File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 113, in handle_request
    for item in respiter:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I cannot find any information on this error and would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Is there a `index.html` file in your current directory?

Comment: No, it is in ./dist, and I specify that when I initialize the flask object. The page is served fine without gunicorn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to return app from main(). The additional arguments in main were unnecessary. I also added a wsgi file:

```
from index import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
else:
    gmain = main()
```

Then ran gunicorn using that file: `gunicorn -k eventlet -b 0.0.0.0:8000 -w 1 wsgi:gmain` and it worked. Seleniumwire threw errors but that is outside the scope of this question.